# Too many Firebase Libraries added in Project

Tags: android, firebase

I am using Android Studio, and I want to use Firebase Analytics and Firebase Ads (AdMob).  I followed all the available documentation and added the following in my app level gradle file, in the dependencies section:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.1'
```

However, I noticed that under the Project's "External Libraries" there was a ton of Firebase libraries that I don't want to use (see image).

[External Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7JH4.png)

I don't know how all these got into the project workspace, if they will be included in the build, and if I can just go ahead and delete them.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unneeded Firebase libraries were actually coming from the Google Play Service dependency (compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1').

I'm not very familiar with Android and all these libraries, so I couldn't see the relationship between the Google Play Service and Firebase libraries, and this why I hadn't mentioned it in my question.

Anyway, I removed it and all the unneeded Firebase libraries were removed from the project.  Now I'll just add the specific Google Play Services API as needed for my app instead of the whole google play dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have all of those for that set of dependencies, but you will have some extra.

You can run:

```
  ./gradlew app:dependencies
```

(assuming your module is called "app") to see a list of dependencies. For me this results in the below list.

`+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.6.1
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0 -> 24.2.1 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.6.1
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.6.1
|         |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:9.6.1
|              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|              +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:9.6.1
|              |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
|              |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.6.1 (*)
|              \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.6.1 (*)
\--- com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.1
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.1
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:9.6.1
     |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
     |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.6.1 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-clearcut:9.6.1
     |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1 (*)
     |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass:9.6.1
     |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1 (*)
     \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.6.1 (*)`

All of the libraries here are as expected - its a mix of the common code for various parts of Firebase, the Analytics library from core and the `play-services-ads` library.

Make sure you've done a clean build since changing your Gradle file, and check for any thing which may depend on other com.google.firebase libraries (such as FirebaseUI).

Comment: I did what you said and strangely enough the output I get from the ./gradlew app:dependencies command includes dependencies to all the libraries I mentioned in my question, e.g. firebase-auth, firebase-crash, etc, which I don't use! I have no idea what FirebaseUI is that you mentioned. I just want firebase analytics and ads, and I have no idea how all these other libraries ended up in my project.  Beside AdMob, I have also added InMobi and Leadbolt SDKs for mediation, but I don't these have created the problem. I Cleaned the Project, but no change.  Is there something else I can do?